# If the wave function can be collapsed, can we collapse the particle function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, wave-particle-duality, wavefunction-collapse

No doubt it's been questioned before so what is the theory or experiment? If there is an experiment.

Comment: Particle function is not a term I am familiar with, could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you mean "probability density function"?  Is "particle function" a term of art in particle physics?

Comment: Well the wave function of light can be collapsed as seen in the double-slit experiment through a particle detector. So I was thinking have we done a vice versa of this, where a particle behavior is caused to act like a wave because of a wave detector.

Comment: I guess it isn't a term though.

Comment: I can't think of anything that would qualify as a wave detector.  Actually, strictly speaking I can't think of anything that would qualify as a particle detector, either.  All detectors operate, ultimately, by "transferring" an  excitation from one system (the object in question) to another (the detector).  It detects excitations, not waves, not particles.  At least that's how it seems to me after trying to imagine what a wave detector would be.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri no, "particle function" is meaningless in particle physics as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your question and the comments beneath, your use of the term "particle function" has no real meaning.

I think I understand what you are asking, something like...
We have proved that waves (light) can act as a particles through the double slit experiment. Is there a method to prove that matter (particles) can act an a wavelike manner?

The answer of course is yes!
We have used the particle equivalent of the DS expt. which is electron diffraction. We can shoot a beam of electrons through a diffracting crystal (the lattice of the crystal acts as the slits) and we are able to see a diffraction pattern:
[image]

Apologies if this is not the question you're asking.

Comment: @user42407 Glad to be of help :)